# Trying to get a mean of CSV files after using concat()

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, concatenation

I have a directory of 20 CSV files so I have used the `concat` function to load them all in for reading purposes. However, I would like to take a mean of the columns but it's not working for me. Here is what I have so far...

```
path = r'/Users/Bry/Desktop/data'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*csv")

df = []
for filename in filenames:
    df.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
pd.concat(df, ignore_index =False)
df.mean()
```

I keep getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'`

Comment: `df` is a `list`, not a `DataFrame`, as your initialisation of it and the error message tell you.

Comment: How would I change it to a data frame?

Comment: What do you mean *back*? It wasn't one to start with. You don't assign the result of `pd.concat`, which I think is what you want.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - what does *"still will not"* mean? A different error? An unexpected value? No value at all?

Comment: [Edit] the question

Comment: thanks for the help. I needed to use the .iterrows() to go through the rows

Answer (score 2):

`pd.concat` returns concatenated `DataFrame` which you are ignoring.

```
mergedf = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=False)
mergedf.mean()
```

I am storing the return value of `pd.concat` in `mergedf`. Then you use this `mergedf` data frame to find mean and do other stuff.